ClassNotFoundException from BaseDexClassLoader
I am trying to integrate the Google Cardboard SDK into my application. I was able to compile the native code without any issue, but at runtime the call to Cardboard_initializeAndroid causes the following stacktrace
12-04 10:45:34.626 27146 27179 W System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.cardboard.sdk.qrcode.CardboardParamsUtils" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
12-04 10:45:34.629 27146 27179 W System.err:    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
12-04 10:45:34.629 27146 27179 W System.err:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
12-04 10:45:34.630 27146 27179 W System.err:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
12-04 10:45:34.630 27146 27179 W System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.cardboard.sdk.QrCodeCaptureActivity" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
12-04 10:45:34.631 27146 27179 W System.err:    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
12-04 10:45:34.631 27146 27179 W System.err:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
12-04 10:45:34.631 27146 27179 W System.err:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
12-04 10:45:34.631 27146 27179 F hello_xr.vulka: java_vm_ext.cc:577] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: RegisterNatives received NULL jclass
12-04 10:45:34.631 27146 27179 F hello_xr.vulka: java_vm_ext.cc:577]     in call to RegisterNatives

It originates form the function LoadJNIResources from qr_code.cc in the native code, which load some Java code that is seemingly not found.
I found a few posts talking about enabling Multidex but my project minSdkVersion is set to 26 and that should be enabled by default.
I've ran apktool on the produced apk file, and grepping for both classes in the output show that the .smali files are in the apk.
I also tried to manually extract the ndk .arr like the hellocardboard-android example does but without success.
I rewrote some parts of the build process. The native code is compiled through CMake somewhere else as a static library, and the build.gradle file looks like this.
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 31
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'

        defaultConfig {
            consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'sdk/proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        // Sets path to java, jni, resources files and manifest location as it is not the default one.
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'sdk/qrcode/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['sdk/qrcode/android/java', 'sdk/device_params/android/java', 'sdk/screen_params/android/java', 'sdk/java_utils/android/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['sdk/qrcode/android/res']
        }
        // Adds proto file and generated source files
        main.java.srcDirs += "${protobuf.generatedFilesBaseDir}/main/javalite"
        main.proto.srcDirs = ["proto"]
        main.proto.includes = ["cardboard_device.proto"]
    }
    namespace 'com.google.cardboard.sdk'
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.19.4'
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                java {
                    option "lite"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    // Android Mobile Vision
    // TODO(b/217176538) Migrate to ML Kit.
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.19.4'
}

It is included in my other project using the implementation project(...) directive in the dependency block.
